# Linq to sql equivalent query to sql server query

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm running the following LINQ to sql query but it returns no results..
But when I run it [equivalent] in sql server it returns data !!

```
 select * from [LocalizedProperty]
 where LanguageId = 3
 and LocaleValue like '%cards%'
 and (LocaleKey = 'Name' or LocaleKey = 'Description')
```

and linq query

```
Dim suggesstions As IEnumerable(Of LocalizedProperty) = _
                   (From sugg In result
                    Where sugg.LanguageId = 3 _
                    AndAlso sugg.LocaleValue.Contains(catalogRetrieveInfo.search_term) _
                    AndAlso (sugg.LocaleKey = "Name" OrElse sugg.LocaleKey = "Description") Select sugg)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is , when i run the query in sql server it returns data..
but when i run it using LINQ it does not return .. so are they equivalent ? correct syntax in linq

Comment: You cannot , you need to translate it

Comment: I think you are trying to run linq query directly in ssms right ? if yes then you cannot do that \

Comment: No, i have a page gets the result from table name LocalizedProperty..
and i want to filter the results using Linq .. i show here an example only.. 
that if i run from sql server it gets data.. but on the page no

Comment: the linq query also checks on a search term and the sql does not so these are not the same queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it will be like this .

```
from sugg In result Where sugg.LanguageId == 3 && sugg.LocaleValue.Contains(catalogRetrieveInfo.search_term) && sugg.LocaleKey == "Name" || sugg.LocaleKey == "Description" select sugg
```

You can also use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to try and test you query. Using LINQPad you can translate LINQ query to SQL.

let me know how it worked for you.